# mysql convert date to same date of current year

Tags: mysql, date

How can I replace the year of a date column with that of the current year?

the following returns `NULL`

```
SELECT str_to_date(concat(year(now()), '-',
month(datecolumn), '-' ,day(datecolumn)), '%Y-%M-%D')
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: In which format `datecolumn` is stored in database ?

Comment: Its stored as a `DATETIME` but in fact the time is never used its always `00:00:00`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Khalid's answer is correct most of the time. Leap year messes things up! If you run the proposed query where the value of datecol is '2016-02-29' and the CURRENT_DATE is '2017-01-01', for example, you get `null`.

<s>An alternate way to do this that handles leap year more gracefully is like this:</s>

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(
    MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()), DAYOFYEAR(datecol)),
    '%Y-%m-%d'
) `date`
FROM t
```

The value of `date` here would be 2017-03-01.

Edit/clarification: The problem is that changing the year of '2016-02-29' to 2017, for example, produces '2017-02-29', which is not a valid date. Then, running DATE_FORMAT('2017-02-29', '%Y-%m-%d') results in `null`. A demo of the problem is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5358/11

However, after reviewing my answer I realized that I another problem by using MAKEDATE since any date on a leap year after Feb 28 is days+1 for a "normal" year with 365 days. For example, if datecol = '2016-03-01' and the current year were 2017 then the converted date would be '2017-03-02', not '2017-03-01' as desired. A better approach is as follows:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(datecol, INTERVAL (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(datecol)) YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d') `date`
FROM t;
```

This method turns any Feb 29th into the 28th, and otherwise keeps all other dates exactly as you'd expect them. A demo of the solution is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5358/12

Comment: Looks like I'd better go back and review one of my projects! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do so

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),RIGHT(datecol,15))  `date`
FROM t
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60e32/2)

Or for date only

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(
CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),RIGHT(datecol,15))
,'%Y-%m-%d')  `date`
FROM t
```

### [Demo 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60e32/6)