# Mysql Birthday query for all years

Tags: mysql

I have a customers table and I would like to filter all the customers whose birthday is between a given date range, let's say January 1st and March 15th.
I've been trying to use:

`(DAY(birthday) >= 01 AND MONTH(birthday) >= 01) AND (DAY(birthday) <= 15 AND MONTH(birthday) <= 03)`

but this will return only the ones whose birthday is between day 1 and 15. 1 to 15 of January, 1 to 15 of February and 1 to 15 of March. Isn't there a way to do this:

`birthday BETWEEN '%-01-01' AND '%-03-15'`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date between dates, ignore year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597491/date-between-dates-ignore-year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use [DayOfYear](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear) to get the day number in a year, so 1 jan is day 1. And 1 aug is day 213.

This wil ignore the year completely.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE DayOfYear(`birthday`)
BETWEEN DayOfYear('01-01-01') AND DayOfYear('2200-03-15')
```

Found: [Date between dates, ignore year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597491/date-between-dates-ignore-year)

Comment: Aug 1 will be Day 214 on leap years. Birthdays are celebrated on the same date usually, irrelevant if its a leap year or not. year 2200 is not a leap year, btw.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CASE` with `WHERE`, e.g.:

```
WHERE
  CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(birthday) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN DAY(birthday) BETWEEN 1 AND 31
    WHEN MONTH(birthday) = 3 THEN DAY(birthday) BETWEEN 1 AND 15
    ELSE FALSE
  END
```